# Add drawing/painting functionality to my activity/fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I'm confused on how to add drawing/painting functionality to my existing system. I have an Activity that controls 3 Fragments through a Tab Bar and I want to be able to add drawing/painting on the Fragment screens in my app. My Fragments already have their own views/layout with checkboxes, text views, etc.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. And there are some libraries which can allow you to do that easily.

Please try these,

- [CanvasView](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView)
- [Android-Hand-Writing](https://github.com/swapgo20/Android-Hand-Drawing)
- [Ink](https://github.com/simplifycom/ink-android)
- [Android Signature Pad](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)

I am sure this will help you. You can either choose to use these libraries directly in your app or you can learn from their source code and implement your own.

But I am sure these resources will be enough to solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Taking specific example of the `CanvasView`,

Pu this in your fragment XML,

```
<com.android.graphics.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Reference the view in code like this,

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {
    private CanvasView canvas = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

        // Create the instance of CanvasView
        this.canvas = (CanvasView)this.findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    }

    // ....
}
```

There are various customization's you can try like,

```
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.PEN);               // Use Pen Tool
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.LINE);              // Draw Line
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.RECTANGLE);         // Draw Rectangle
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.CIRCLE);            // Draw Circle
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.ELLIPSE);           // Draw Ellipse (Oval)
this.canvas.setDrawer(CanvasView.Drawer.QUADRATIC_BEZIER);  // Draw Quadratic Bezier
```

And these,

```
this.canvas.setPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
this.canvas.setPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
this.canvas.setPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
```

There are lots of other cuztomizations you can try. Just check the resource I have provided you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! The thing I'm confused about however is that most of these approaches are shown creating their own activity or view, but I already have activities and views that I wan't to add this functionality to. How would I add a DrawingView to my existing screens if my Activity and Fragments already have their own layout views.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide detailed help to you. Please accept the answer, if it has helped you.

Comment: @Arita Thanks! One more thing if you wouldn't mind. Is it possible to get this CanvasView to sit underneath the content I already have in my Fragments? My fragments are filled with checkboxes and textviews but I'd like for the user to be able to draw anywhere. As it is, it seems like putting the CanvasView at the top of my layout covers everything else.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Just use a FrameLayout for that. Put the CanvasView first and then put all other Views over it.

Comment: @Arita Thanks a lot! One of the most helpful answers I've gotten here. Is that CanvasView open source? Am I able to copy that file into my code?

Comment: Glad that I could help you.

Comment: @Arita Was I able to copy that CanvasView.java into my project and eventually distribute this as an app? I see it says copyright so I'm unsure.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just include the license in your app.

Comment: @AritraRoy Hi Sorry to bring the topic up again I've found your answer rather useful, However, I'm encountering some problem using the API. Is there a way to omit the initializing of the CanvasView object upon starting the app? Because I only want to call it within onActivityResult() class after taking a picture for user to paint.

Comment: What initialization are you talking about? Have not looked into the API for long, so please elaborate specifically.

Comment: @AritraRoy Running the application for the first time. When the app was first started by the user. The CanvasView object was also started but I want to suppress this. Because I'm building an app somewhat like a photo editing app where the CanvasView only starts after user have taken a picture via the camera and is ready to paint on the bitmap.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any reason or this not to work. Why not keep the view GONE and make it VISIBLE only when you need it to be?